# No suggested imports for React Testing Library in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-testing-library

I am setting up a Next JS Typescript project that uses React Test Library. However I am unable to get the suggested imports working in my VS Code. As a really basic example consider this test in the /**tests**/components/card/index.tsx file

[image]

However here I have manually imported `render`. If I do not do this and try and use the suggested import, I get this:

[image]

Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue using RemixJS.

I solved it by adding any needed types to my existing `env.d.ts`, like:

```
/* These were already present in the file: */
/// <reference types="@remix-run/node" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

/* Needed to add these so Intellisense would suggest the correct imports: */
/// <reference types="@testing-library/react" />
/// <reference types="@remix-run/testing" />
```